# The two forms of Henon map

Tags: dynamical-systems

The widely-used form of Henon map, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non_map), is
$$
\begin{cases}x_{n+1} = 1-a x_n^2 + y_n\\y_{n+1} = b x_n.\end{cases}
$$

However, in some other places, for example in the [manual](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/sandsted/auto/auto07p.pdf) of `auto07p`, there is an alternative form:
$$
\begin{cases}x'_{n+1} = a- {x'}_n^{2} -b y'_n\\y'_{n+1} = x'_n.\end{cases}
$$

**My questions are**: Is there a formal relation, e.g. a coordinate transformation, between these two forms of Henon map? If yes, what is the formal relation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent and there's a simple relation between them.
It's sufficient to check a $x = \alpha u $, $y = \beta v$ change of variables. Let's do this:

\begin{cases}\overline{x} = 1-a x^2 + y\\\overline{y} = b x.\end{cases}

then:

\begin{cases} \alpha\overline{u} = 1-a \alpha^2 u^2 + \beta v\\ \beta\overline{v} = b \alpha u.\end{cases}

after that:

\begin{cases} \overline{u} = \frac{1}{\alpha}-a \alpha u^2 + \frac{\beta}{\alpha} v\\\overline{v} = \frac{b}{\beta} \alpha u.\end{cases}

And now let's choose appropriate constants:

$$ \alpha a = 1 $$
$$ b \alpha = \beta$$

At last we obtain:

\begin{cases} \overline{u} = a-u^2 + b v\\\overline{v} = u.\end{cases}

After this change of variables Henon map of form I with parameters $(a, b)$ becomes Henon map of form II with parameters $(a, -b)$.

Comment: Nice, I was thinking why Henon map of form I with parameters $(a,b)$ but Henon map of form II has parameters $(a,-b)$?